# Concatenate Values and associated Headers using TEXTJOIN

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, concatenation, textjoin

I'm currently 2 separate TEXTJOIN functions to return all values in table rows (which aren't blank) and to return the headers associated with these.

To extract values (Output1):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,IF(C7:XL7<>0,C7:XL7,""))}
```

To extract headers (Output2):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,IF(C7:XL7<>0,$C$5:$XL$5,""))}
```

Current outputs are something like:

```
name       project1      project2       Output          Output2
User1      0001                         0001            project1
User2      0002          0003           0002 + 0003     project1 + project2
User3      0001          0001           0001 + 0001     project1 + project2
```

When what I really want is one single output, with the value header (in round brackets), before moving onto the next column:

```
name       project1      project2       Output
User1      0001                         0001 (project1)
User2      0002          0003           0002 (project1) + 0003 (project2)
User3      0001          0001           0001 (project1) + 0001 (project2)
```

Is somehow merging the two formulas above possible to output something similar to this? Array formulas make my head spin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to ARRAY enter the formula IMHO.

You can try below approach:

`=TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,C7:XL7&IF(C7:XL7<>""," ("&$C$5:$XL$5&")",""))`

**PS:** I have tested this formula in web-version of Office 365 where it doesn't need ARRAY entry to show the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually works (although only when I set it to an array formula). I'll just need to spend time understanding exactly what it's doing.

Comment: the newer version of Office 365 do not need the CSE, but anything else will need it.  It is an array formula, but Office 365 has Dynamic Array formula and automatically shifts into array mode.

Comment: @ScottCraner, that explains it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation. Do you mind explaining what role the 2 '&' symbols play that enclose C5:XL5?

Comment: @AJNW1991 It is used as concatenation operator. You should use formula evaluate option to see the workings.